# Optional filters using LINQ to Entities

Tags: c, linq-to-entities, ienumerable

I got this class:

```
public class PedidosList
    {
        public virtual int ID_Pedido { get; set; }        
        public virtual int Numero { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime FechaEntrega { get; set; }
        public virtual int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual string Cliente { get; set; }
        public virtual Decimal Bruto { get; set; }
        public virtual Decimal Neto { get; set; }
        public virtual Boolean Aprobado { get; set; }
        public virtual string Observaciones { get; set; }
        public virtual Boolean Entregado { get; set; }
    }
```

To represent a subset of fields from a POCOs class map to an SQL Table with Entity Framework. Then use this function to make optional filter using Linq to Entities and return a IENumerable colection:

```
public IEnumerable<PedidosList> Pedidos_Listar(string sComprobante, Clientes MyCliente = null, DateTime? dDesde = null, DateTime? dHasta = null, bool bCumplidos = false)
        {           
            using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
            {
                IEnumerable<PedidosList> query =
                    from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
                    join Clientes in context.Clientes on Pedidos.ID_Cliente equals Clientes.ID_Cliente
                    where Pedidos.ID_Comprobante == sComprobante                    
                    select new PedidosList {ID_Pedido = Pedidos.ID_Pedido, Fecha=Pedidos.Fecha, Aprobado=Pedidos.Aprobado, Bruto=Pedidos.Bruto, Cliente=Clientes.RazonFantasia, 
                        FechaEntrega=Pedidos.FechaEntrega, Neto=Pedidos.Neto, Numero=Pedidos.Numero, Observaciones=Pedidos.Observaciones, Entregado=Pedidos.Entregado, ID_Cliente=Pedidos.ID_Cliente };

                if (MyCliente != null) query = query.Where(i => i.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente);
                if (MyCliente != null) query = query.Where(i => i.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente);
                if (dDesde != null && dHasta != null) query = query.Where(i => i.Fecha >= dDesde && i.Fecha <= dHasta);
                if (bCumplidos == false) query = query.Where(i => i.Entregado == false);                
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }
```

So my questions: Is this the best way to achive this? Can i make an optional filter adding a new where on a field that is on Pedidos but not on PedidosList? Example: i have to add the field ID_Cliente to PedidosList ONLY so i can filter even if i don't want it on PedidosList. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm super late answering this, but I just came across it. I wouldn't be particularly uncomfortable with what you've done, I think it's mostly a matter of personal preference and what you consider readable. But if I were to write it, I would probably do something like this.

```
public IEnumerable<PedidosList> Pedidos_Listar(string sComprobante, Clientes MyCliente = null, DateTime? dDesde = null, DateTime? dHasta = null, bool bCumplidos = false)
{           
    using (var context = new OhmioEntities())
    {
        return from Pedidos in context.Pedidos
               join Clientes in context.Clientes on Pedidos.ID_Cliente equals Clientes.ID_Cliente
               where (Pedidos.ID_Comprobante == sComprobante) &&
                     (MyCliente == null || Pedidos.ID_Cliente == MyCliente.ID_Cliente) &&
                     (dDesde == null || dHasta == null || Pedidos.Fecha >= dDesde && Pedidos.Fecha <= dHasta) &&
                     (bCumplidos || Pedidosi.Entregado)
               select new PedidosList
                      {
                          ID_Pedido = Pedidos.ID_Pedido,
                          Fecha = Pedidos.Fecha,
                          Aprobado = Pedidos.Aprobado,
                          Bruto = Pedidos.Bruto,
                          Cliente = Clientes.RazonFantasia, 
                          FechaEntrega = Pedidos.FechaEntrega,
                          Neto = Pedidos.Neto,
                          Numero = Pedidos.Numero,
                          Observaciones = Pedidos.Observaciones,
                          Entregado = Pedidos.Entregado,
                          ID_Cliente = Pedidos.ID_Cliente
                      };
    }
}
```

The one thing I would be pretty tempted to change on what you did, though, is that I wouldn't include your `ToList()` at the end. That negates some of the benefits of using `IEnumerable<T>`.